# How to get date (day/month/year) from MonthCalendar in C++ Builder 6?

Tags: c++, datetimepicker, c++builder, vcl, monthcalendar

I'm creating an age counter app, but I couldn't use the date, which is user chose from the calendar. How can I use the day/month/year specified in MonthCalendar in my program?

[image: monthcalendar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TMonthCalendar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TMonthCalendar) has a [`Date`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCommonCalendar.Date) property, which returns the user's selected date as a [`TDateTime`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime) value.  You can extract the individual month, day, and year values from that, if needed, by using the [`TDateTime::DecodeDate()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime.DecodeDate) method.

```cpp
TDateTime dtSelected = MonthCalendar1->Date;
Word wYear, wMonth, wDay;
dtSelected.DecodeDate(&wYear, &wMonth, &wDay);
...
```